# Loading images after page is completed (not lazy load)

Tags: image

So there is this tech blog site called "verge" :http://www.theverge.com/

When you first go there, the images are loaded after the page is completed.

(There is only the background color until the page is loaded, then the images are loaded)

How can I achieve the same thing in wordpress?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is ommiting the sources until after load and then inserting them with Javascript. Browsers are very aggressive towards loading stuff as early as they can.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="actualImage.png"/>
```

Be aware that an empty source [generates an additional request on the document](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/). There are several ways to work around that, one is a transparent pixel as base64 string.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    var delayedImages = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
    for (var i = 0; i < delayedImages.length; i++) {
        delayedImages[i].src = delayedImages[i].getAttribute("data-src");
    }
});
```

Also be aware that ommitting images that affect the flow of your page (the size of its containers) will cause the loading process look twitchy so it would be better if the images had a size set by css.

You can also just use [this wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-image-loader/) which does exactly that (for images in the content and featured images). It also loads the visible images before the images below the fold (and optionally lazy loads those).